# Wacom Intuos Express Keys Not Working Properly

Tags: shortcut-keys, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos Medium Art tablet, which isn't working properly.

It almost works right; I can use the pen, and touch properly -- sensitivity for the pen, and even the pen's buttons are all working fine -- however, the express keys on the tablet are broken in an odd way.

---

Out of the 4 buttons on the tablet, only three work. What's more is that they are mapped to the wrong corresponding positions as seen on the GUI (found under the GNOME settings menu). 
I can't seem to take a screen shot of this, but to elaborate, if I press the top left button, I am prompted to bind for the top right. If I press the bottom left button, I am prompted to bind for the top left. If I press the bottom right button, everything works fine! I am prompted to bind the bottom right... But if I press the top right button, I am not prompted at all, I can't seem to bind this express key whatsoever. Something I have noticed though, is that it can detect the button in some way, because if I am being prompted for a different express key when I press the top right button, the prompt will be canceled, however I still won't receive a new prompt.

---

I have done a lot of research on the problem, but I can't seem to find anyone with the same issue as me. I also tried all the fixes I could find for people with similar issues, but none of them seem to work...

First, I thought I could be missing some dependencies (which I was), however upon downloading them through apt, and rebooting, nothing was any better.

---

Next, I tried building from source. I did this, following the directions to the T for each of the downloads on the linux wacom website (http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads). This didn't help.

---

Then, I updated my kernel from 4.10 to 4.14, and this still didn't fix anything.

(Just to note, I'm running Ubuntu 17.04)

---

Lastly, I tried manually setting the express keys through `xsetwacom`, somehow with even less luck. When I used the command `xsetwacom --list devices` the ouput was as follows:

```
Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pen stylus      id: 13  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Finger touch    id: 14  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pad pad         id: 15  type: PAD
```

I was then able to map an express key to the bottom right button through `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pad pad" Button 1 key "..."`. However when I did the same thing but for Button 2, nothing happened. I read up on this and apparently this is normal, so I continued. `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pad pad" Button 3 key "..."` successfully mapped to the top left button. However, despite this progress, I was unable to map any other buttons past 3. When I used the command `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pad pad" Button 4 key "..."` the output was as follows

```
Unsupported offset into 'Wacom Button Actions' property.
```

And any other number beyond three yielded the same response, so I was actually able to bind more keys with the GUI.

(Just to note, I was substituting actual keybinds with `...` -- while I was testing it I used `f5` and tested it by attempting to refresh a webpage.)

---

None of these working brought me here. If anyone has any ideas, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map buttons 1,3,8, and 9.

Did you read the following info?

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Consumer-Tablet-ExpressKey-Mapping-Issue

Comment: Thank you! As I said in the body, I couldn't get Button 4 to work, with xsetwacom, and so I tried 5, 6, and a bunch of other random one's above 3, and when that didn't work, I assumed nothing would. But as you said, 1, 3, 8, and 9 appear to work.

Comment: I executed the script and mapped the buttons then press q. It did not work. My wacom table pad button still has no effects. Note that the tablet pad worked flawlessly for several weeks and then, yesterday, it stopped working. I was able to make it work after executing the same script and a couple of reboots, but today it doesn't seem to want to work. I don't know what else I should do.